# Canonical Projections are Continuous

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I was wondering if one would be so kind as to critique my short proof that the canonical projections are continuous with respect to the product topology:

Let $\pi_i : \prod X_k \rightarrow X_i$ be one of the canonical projections, and $V_i$ some open set in $X_i$. Then $\pi^{-1}_i(V_i) = \prod V_k$, where $V_k = X_k$ for all $k \neq i$, which is clearly basis element (and therefore open) in the product topology.

Now we justify the set equality. Let $x \in \pi_i^{-1}(V_i)$. This happens if and only if $\pi_i(x) \in V_i$ or $x_i \in V_i$ and $x_k \in X_k$ for every $k \neq i$. Hence, $\pi^{-1}_i(V_i) = \prod V_k$.

---

Moreover, I am wondering if I can conclude that the projections are also continuous with respect to the box topology, since it is finer than product topology.

Comment: Yes, your proof goes through for both product and box topologies.

Comment: The Tychonoff produt topology is defined to be the weakest topology on the product-set that makes the projections continuous. So the projections will be continuous with respect to any finer topology.